# Convert HTML tables to Java

Tags: android, html, parsing, html-table

I would like to download websites filled with tables and then convert then into something like an arraylist.

Is this possible with a parser? If so, can you please provide me some parsers that can be able to do that such as libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to code this yourself. It's very hard to get right and it's a mess. There are a number of open-source HTML parser libraries in Java. See [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers) for a reasonably good list of them. Start with one of those and then post a follow-up question if you get stuck on something.

Comment: I am trying to get sports statistics and it is all stored in Tables. I can extract the data (String), however, I would like to store the links to team logos. I can't seem to do that :(

Comment: @bluejamesbond - Are you sure what you're doing is allowed? Most sites TOS tell you not to scrape their info.

Comment: @SpencerRuport: i am making an app for my school and it is for not for profit so i am guessing they should allow me. and i will hand the app to the school if i do complete it.

Comment: @bluejamesbond - Unless the terms of service expressly say "you may scrape this site if you're writing a not for profit app" (which it won't) that doesn't make a difference. If a site wants to make their information available for 3rd party use they will always create a web service API. It doesn't matter if this is just for school or not.

Comment: @Spencer Ruport - the website is also of the very school for which I am making the app for. ill make it and then give it to them...then its all theirs to use or not. i really hope this will work out

Comment: @Spencer Ruport - i want to scrape...[link] (http://m.tamu.edu/photos) and then store the images and etc in text and imageviews...however, it is so hard to get those links out and store them

Comment: @bluejamesbond - If this is the school you're writing the project for it would make much more sense to contact the IT department and ask them to provide an RSS version of the mobile site links. That way you could easily parse the content.

Comment: @Spencer Ruport - do you think they can do that?